# How to make endless loop for string checking in file (java)

Tags: java

I want to write a program which would check the file line by line and tell if the data exists in that file, when user inputs the data. 
So far i have this code right here (it is not mine):

```
package ibanas;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadFromFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    Scanner sc = new Scanner(ReadFromFile.class.getResourceAsStream("file.txt"));
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("What number would you like to check for?");
    String number = myScanner.nextLine() ;
    int lineNum = 0;
    String word="";
    while(sc.hasNextLine()) {
        word = sc.nextLine();

        if(word.equals(number.trim())) { 
            System.out.println("The number "+number+ " is there");

            return;
        } else {

        }
    } 
    System.out.println("not found"); 
}
}
```

And here is the txt file:

```
LT647044001231465456
AA051245445454552117989
LT517044077788877777
LT227044077788877777
CC051245445454552117989
```

And one more thing - when i enter the first line number  LT647044001231465456 , it shows not found, but it is in that txt file, so i cant figure whats the problem with that. With other four numbers everything is okay. 
And it would be great if it would endlessly ask for input, because the program now stops when if statement is complete. Should i put the if statement in some kind of a loop which would roll untill reaches != null?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Did you try debugging it?. Check what value you get the first time around

Comment: just tested it; seems to work

Comment: @TheLostMind i tried debugging it, but it seems like im stuck at it, in show view -> debug,Thread[ [main] (Running) is always running. If i got this right, it shouldn't be like this?

Comment: By the way, does anyone have an idea how to make a loop, so it would be always asking for input evem after if statement is complete? :)

Comment: Look at my answer below..that would ask for input forever  ;)

Answer (score 0):

To solve at least your second problem:
You should extract the search logic into another method like search().
Then you could make a simple infinite loop in main() that starts calling the recursive search() method.
And at the end of every search() you call search() again

```
search(params)
{
   code..
   search()
}
```

you can also do a while(true) loop. In both solutions you should have some termination condition. and you shouldnd come to an "return" keyword in the main() method itself.

For the first problem with the not found number even if it exists. You could avoid some possible misstakes with word.toLowerCase() and number.toLowerCase().
Then you can compare abc123 with ABC123.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make while(true) before creation of first scanner and replace return; with break; and make variable which indicates if search was successful:

```
while(true){
boolean found = false;
Scanner sc = ...

...if(word.equals(number.trim())) { 
        System.out.println("The number "+number+ " is there");
        found = true;
        break; //return;
    }
}
if(!found){
System.out.println("not found");
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: did like you said, it works, but with one little problem: if the user input doesn't match, it gives not found, everything is okay, but when the user input matches the txt file, it gives output "the number is there" and "not found" at the same time. Any ideas?:)

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
package ibanas;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ReadFromFile {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {


    Scanner sc = null;
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int lineNum = 0;
    String word="";
    boolean found = false;
    while(true) {
        sc = new Scanner(ReadFromFile.class.getResourceAsStream("file.txt"));
        System.out.println("What number would you like to check for?");
        String number = myScanner.nextLine() ;
        found = false;  

        while(sc.hasNextLine())
        {
            word = sc.nextLine();

            if(word.equals(number.trim())) { 
                System.out.println("The number "+number+ " is there");
                found = true;   
                break;

            } 
        }
        if(!found) 
        {
            System.out.println("not found"); 
        }
        sc.close();
    } 
}
}
```